# Sqlite: Create a table and fill with information only once

Tags: sqlite, insert, appcelerator

I have an appcelerator titanium project (you don't need to be familiar with the platform to help me) that I am using to create an iOS app. I want to have a database with a table that is filled with several rows for the first time, and then left alone after the first time.

I know you can create a table if it doesn't exist. Is there something similar for Inserting data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on MPelletier's response with some Titanium-specific code, you could do the following in your project:

```
var my_db = Ti.Database.open('nameofdb');
var my_result_set = my_db.execute('SELECT * FROM MyTable');
var records = my_result_set.rowCount;
```

The records variable will indicate whether or not you have data in your table and then you can act accordingly.

There are a couple of nice ORM-ish utilities out there for Titanium: TiStore and Joli are the two I've used. Both are inspired by ActiveRecord and can be helpful in reducing your DB-related code. They're on Github if you want to know more about them!

Answer (score 0):

There's INSERT OR REPLACE if you want, but you might as well just check against the number of rows on the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable;
```

Then decide to enter them on that.

Comment: So if I have a table called MyTable will that command above just return the number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your DB and insert data in it via SQLLiteManager or whatever tool you want and then dump it.

Take the file you dumped, put it in your Titanium project folder (somewhere in the Resources folder).

Then this line of code will take the content of the .sqlite file and insert it in the iOS db:

```
var db = Ti.Database.install('../your-db.sqlite', 'your-db-name');
```

Just don't forget the CREATE IF NOT EXISTS statement in your SQL file.

Or use REPLACE instead of INSERT as MPelletier said.